# Insert variable URL jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var varName ="vendor1";
$('#wishlistIframe').load('http://sito.it/varName .wk-mp-rating-right');
```

Hello, i'd like to know if is possible to append varName variable into URL in order to get the final result: http://sito.it/vendor1

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use this `` instead of '' and variable inside ${}

$('#wishlistIframe').load(`http://sito.it/${varName} .wk-mp-rating-right`);